# Random Forest Model sci kit learn specifying columns

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am building a random forest model using sci kit learn and python, and I want to be able to specify which columns want to be included. The model is to predict the value of 'pages' based on values of 'size1', 'size2', and 'size3'. The value of label is dependent on the value of 'seconds', but that should not matter for the model. However, I want to be able to include as few or as many columns as I want, for example, I may want to just use 'size1', or both 'size2' and 'size3', etc. How can I do this? Right now, I am using all 50 columns of data to make my model, and I want to be able to specify which columns I want to incorporate. Thank you! I have attached some code I have currently, and a sample of what the data looks like.

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:50].values
```

[image]

Comment: You write "all 50 columns" but you also say your columns are "'size1', 'size2', and 'size3'" so your question is a bit confusing given the data you present (which appears to show 5 [potential] predictors and one predicted column).

Comment: @xibalba1 I have created sample data with only a few variables, but in my actual data, I have 50 rows. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: `X = dataset[['size1', 'size2']]`?

Comment: @ywbaek Thank you so much!